# How I can create user defined roles

Tags: mongodb, security, permissions

I have a database in mongoDB 2.6.4 in which I want to restrict the users as per their level. I want to give read privileges to some users and insert/update privileges to some other users on a particular database. Please let me know how I can create user defined roles and assign them to the users. I tried the below but it is not working; the users still have full privileges:

```
db.runCommand({createRole: "read",

   privileges: [

         { resource: { db: "sample", collection: "" }, 
                     actions: [ "find" ] 
           }],
   roles: [],

   writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }

             })

==================================================================================

db.addUser( { user : "read",
              pwd  : "read",
              roles:["read"]
        } )
```

Comment: Are the users members of other roles in addition to `read`?

Comment: Yes ,we need to provide some user only ready on the database and some user can run CURD operation on a particular database.

Comment: I meant that you should check to make sure that the users don't have other roles which are granting privileges above just read from the `read` role.

Comment: I got that but the user have the below privileges in the read roles "actions" : [
                                "collStats",
                                "dbHash",
                                "dbStats",
                                "find",
                                "killCursors",
                                "planCacheRead"

Comment: but still the user who have read privileges able to create the database as well drop

Comment: 1st The role read is build-in, try use another name, 2nd The role applies to the database on which you run the command, are you sure you run this on the correct database?